# Curl PHP Api V4 Google Sheets

Tags: php, curl, google-sheets

with the following code I call the API v4 to print the values ​​of a spreadsheet. It is going very well.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/
spreadsheetID/values/PHP?valueRenderOption=UNFORMATTED_VALUE&key=yourKeyId");
$result = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
```

What I can't achieve is to do an insert or update on it, I can't manage to put the PHP curl together for this. Some help? Please try as below but it doesn't work.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/
spreadsheetID/append/PHP?InsertDataOption=INSERT_ROWS&key=yourKeyId");
$jvalues=array(array("5869","35685987","Ema","2020-05-29","no brinda","3563430423"));

$jsonData = array(
'values' => $jvalues
 );

$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$result = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
```

[image for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FC5x.png)

Some help, I found no examples anywhere.
Thanks.

Comment: When I saw your script, it seems that you are using an API key. If my understanding is correct, unfortunately, the API key cannot be used for the POST methods while it can be used for the GET method. So it is required for putting values to Google Spreadsheet to use the access token retrieved by OAuth2 and/or the service account. By the way, when the Google Spreadsheet is not yours or you have no permission for writing, even when the access token is used, the values cannot be used. Also please be careful this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the API key cannot be used for the POST methods while it can be used for the GET method. So it is required for putting values to Google Spreadsheet to use the access token retrieved by OAuth2 and/or the service account. By the way, when the Google Spreadsheet is not yours or you have no permission for writing, even when the access token is used, the values cannot be used.

### References:

[Sheets Authorizing requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing)

[OAuth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)